# Generating uniformly distributed points in a simplex

Tags: random-variables, computational-geometry, simplex, monte-carlo

In order to test portfolio strategies I want to generate random points $(w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n)$ inside an $n$-dimensional simplex with constraints:

$$\tag{1}0 \leq w_i \leq 1, \quad \forall i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$$ 
$$\tag{2}\sum_{i=1}^n w_i = 1$$ 
$$\tag{3}\sum_{i,j=1}^n \sigma_{ij}w_iw_j = \sigma^2$$

where $[\sigma_{ij}]$ is a covariance matrix.

I would like the points to be uniformly distributed.  Without constraint (3), this is fairly easy.  For example I can generate independent uniform random numbers $w_i \sim U(0,1)$ for $1 = 1, \ldots, n-1$, set $w_n = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} w_i$, and then discard points outside of the simplex.

The problem is how to incorporate the variance constraint (3).

Comment: The points cannot be uniformly distributed for arbitrary $\sigma^2$.

Comment: One further observations: Even in your fairly simple example $w_n$ is not uniformly distributed.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: Can you show my why that is?

Comment: @WoodWorker:  Imagine the range of variables in any dimension is $1.0$.  How would you obtain a $\sigma^2 = 10^9$?